# Elasticsearch ,multi_match how using multi minimum_should_match

Tags: elasticsearch

ı want  multi `mininmum_should_match` on `multi_match`  query
for example

```
GET /similarity/_search
{
  
  "query": {
    
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Zamana  su miktarı gösterilmiştir. ",
      "fields": ["text1"],
      "type": "best_fields", 
      "minimum_should_match": "5<10%"
    }
  }
}
```

ı want two conditions on `minimum_should_match` as follows, but how ı can do it
**be careful minimum_should_match**

```
GET /similarity/_search
{
  
  "query": {
    
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Zamana  su miktarı gösterilmiştir. ",
      "fields": ["text1"],
      "type": "best_fields", 
      "minimum_should_match": "5<10% 15<%25"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want from a multi minimum should match condition? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: you assume has a long-phrase or short phrase,ı want searching conditional minimum_should_match, for example, if my phrase is  4 words, perform  40%  or for more to long-phrase ı want to perform 90%...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is right.

You could use minimum_should_match condition of 1<40% 4<90%. This means if your number of search tokens are less than or equal to one then all tokens should match, if they are greater than 1 and less than or equal to 4 then 40% should match and if they are greater than 4 then 90% should match.

The thing to keep in mind is that you are using best_fields which is field centric and hence it would generate a minimum_should_match condition for each field. So if you have fields other than "text1", one minimum should match condition would be generated for each. If that is not what you want then you should use cross_fields.
Read more here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html